# imshow only works in the outer scope

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to show the output of each of the stages of my code but imshow doesn't seem to work on the inner functions

I made an empty function with just an imshow line to test this out and it still doesn't show the actual image given to it and instead shows a small image full of 0s

Another observation is it displays each loop image in a separate window called "test" and "original image"
by the end of the loop you have n*2 windows (with those 2 names repeating) where n is the number of images

```py
def test_(clr_img):
    cv2.imshow("test image", clr_img)

def loop_folder(folder_path, save_path, debug=True):
    """Applies the label_chars function to every image in a folder and saves at the save_path
    """
    json_name_list = []
    for file_name in listdir(folder_path):
        if file_name.endswith(".json"):
            json_name_list.append(file_name)

    for json_file_name in tqdm(json_name_list):
        json_path = path.join(folder_path, json_file_name)
        with open(json_path) as json_file_r:
            json_data = json.load(json_file_r)
            image_file_path = json_path.replace(".json", ".png")
            image = cv2.imread(image_file_path)

            if debug:
                img = image.copy()
                cv2.imshow("original image", image) # this one shows everytime
                test_(image) # this one sometimes shows 
            
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm using opencv 4.3.0.36 and python 3.7

Comment: try cv2.waitKey(0) after  cv2.imshow in the inner loop

Comment: I tried putting it in the smaller function and the outer one and both, all give the same result;  not entirely sure if you by the inner loop you mean the other function or not

Comment: can you try to place an initial cv2.namedWindow in outer scope? What's the window title name of all the small windows?

Comment: I don't have a named window, only the windows created with imshow each has its own name, the issue wasn't with the code it was opencv itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was opencv itself, it worked on other PCs so I tried reinstalling opencv and it works as normal now